# No XML response from cURL POST to REST API in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am sending a POST request in PHP via cURL to a REST API that uses XML. When I use Postman or Advanced REST Client, I get a XML response to my POST request. However, when I use PHP and cURL I do not seem able to see back the XML responses. What do I need to do to get these back? Eventually I need to retrieve a token that I can then use to process INSERT, UPDATES and GETS through this API via XML.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'xxxxxx-Username: xxx',
    'xxxxxx-Password: xxx',
    'content-type: application/xml'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

and currently I am getting a blank page. I have tried quite a few solutions, like the following

```
//header("Content-Type: text/xml");
//header('Content-type: application/xml');
//$decoded = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $response);
//echo $decoded;

//echo $response;
//print_r($response);

// set up your xml result
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

// loop through the results
$cnt = count($xml->Result);
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
    echo 'XML : First Name: = ';
}
```

but nothing seems to give me back what I get from Postman or Advanced REST Client, which on this particular command is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuthInfo>
    <token/>
    <AuthStatus>
        <Id>503</Id>
        <Description>There's no proapi manager running with the given company code: crmapp</Description>
    </AuthStatus>
</AuthInfo>
```

I understand that at this stage there is an issue with my url that I need to fix, but I still should be able to receive that error back via XML.

Can anyone please help me get this XML response back so that I can progress my interface?

Thank you in advance,
Adri

Thanks again Professor, here is the full debug with the latest version of PHP and cUrl

```
Verbose debug info

*   Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:443...
* Connected to xxxxx-xx-xx.xxxxxxxx.com.au (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: D:/Adri/PHP/MoW/famac/cacert.pem
*  CApath: D:/Adri/PHP/MoW/famac/cacert.pem
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.prontohosted.com.au
*  start date: Jun  2 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  4 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "xxxxx-xx-xx.xxxxxxxx.com.au" matched cert's "*.xxxxxxxx.com.au"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=Sectigo Limited; CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /xxxxx/rest/xxx.xxx/login HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx-xx-xx.xxxxxxxx.com.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.38
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
xxxxxx-Username: xxx
xxxxxx-Password: xxx
Content-Type: application/xml

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2021 11:34:57 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'self' *.xxxxx.net *.xxxxx.com.au https://www.google.com https://*.googleapis.com/ www.google-analytics.com stats.g.doubleclick.net http://*.xxxxx-xxxxx.com *.twitter.com *.twimg.com data: blob: https://*.google.com https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com; frame-src * blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.xxxxx.net *.xxxxx.com.au https://*.google.com www.google-analytics.com *.twitter.com *.twimg.com  https://*.googleapis.com https://jawj.github.io https://*.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self' wss: blob: *.twitter.com www.google-analytics.com stats.g.doubleclick.net; base-uri 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.twitter.com *.twimg.com https://*.google.com *.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com; font-src 'self' data: https://*.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; child-src * blob:; object-src 'none'; default-src 'self' blob:
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 994
* The requested URL returned error: 404
* Closing connection 0

Info

stdClass Object
(
    [url] => https://xxxxx-xx-xx.xxxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxx/rest/xxx.xxx/login
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 1271
    [request_size] => 350
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.232624
    [namelookup_time] => 0.029367
    [connect_time] => 0.05058
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.162497
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 994
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.232609
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => xxx.xxx.x.xxx
    [local_port] => 52711
    [http_version] => 2
    [protocol] => 2
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => HTTPS
    [appconnect_time_us] => 162464
    [connect_time_us] => 50580
    [namelookup_time_us] => 29367
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 162497
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 232609
    [total_time_us] => 232624
)
```

Can you please let me know what you think of this? While I am no longer getting the previous error, I still seem unable to receive the XML response back. :(

Thank you in advance, Adri

Comment: You are dealing with an SSL enabled endpoint so additional steps are most often required to allow curl to negotiate correctly with the remote host. Your curl config needs to use additional parameters set to work  - my guess is that POSTMAN does this automagically. Download [a copy of the most recent "cacert.pem"](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), save it to your server and then set the appropriate options for cURL - such as ["CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST", "CURLOPT_CAINFO"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Without knowing more details of the remote api and how the authentication if to be done ( is it as shown - headers based? ) it is tricky to offer more info - but one thing of note missing from your curl config is the `useragent` - quite frequently the absence of such will cause remote server to drop the request

Comment: Thank you Professor, yes, you are absolutely right, I am fishing at the moment as I have been unable to get some exact answers from the other software company. I have tried various method of authentication with username and password, but they have all failed via Postman and ARC. When I tried with the headers based structure, I finally got through and started getting a response. I am now still missing a URL correct parameter, or they need to activate something on their application settings, to allow us access into the API.

Comment: I have simply copied the PHP code auto generated from Postman, so I assumed that if it worked in Postman it should have worked for me! Also, on adding useragent, how do I know what value to set in it? Thank you again and sorry for the late reply, due to a GMT +9:30 time zone!

Comment: I have also tried CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, but is not making any difference. By the way, I have just been given the correct URL and I am now receiving the Token in Postman. Not quite sure where to from here to get these XML responses back with PHP cURL! :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The above clearly shows a 404 error. You need to verify that the url you have is correct first of all. Admittedly a 404 can be returned whether the page is found or not so perhaps ask the api support for possible reasons why you are getting a 404 if this is 100% the correct url. How is authentication handled - your original code just shows sending username&password as they are in headers which does seem a little odd

Comment: Thanks Professor, I will investigate further with the API support and report back. I fully agree, authentication seems does seem odd, however from Postman it seems to work. I will report back once I know more. Thanks again.

Comment: Professor, thank you! It is all working as expected now! The API support noticed that we were missing a CURLOPT_POST and explained that the default for CURL is GET. So I added the following line 47 - curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true ); and everything is now working perfectly and I am able to receive the token back! Thank you so much for all your help Professor, I have really appreciated it immensely. Regards, Adri

Comment: ;-) excellent news.. good luck with the rest of your coding adventure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl function I use is as follows. It has extra debugging information in the output and the default settings can be easily overridden at runtime by supplying a different `$options` argument. I'm not suggesting this is the answer but with a better set of options configured and better debug info you should get closer.

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    /*
        Download a copy of CACERT.pem from
        https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
        
        save to webserver and modify the $cacert variable
        to suit - ensuring that the path you choose is
        readable.
    */
    
    $res=array(
        'response'  =>  NULL,
        'info'      =>  array( 'http_code' => 100 ),
        'headers'   =>  NULL,
        'errors'    =>  NULL
    );
    if( is_null( $url ) ) return (object)$res;

    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object - these should be OK as-is */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, $cacert );
    }

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.38' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    
    /* enhanced debug */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
    

    /* Assign runtime parameters as options to override defaults if needed. */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    /* send any headers with the request that are needed */
    if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
$url='https://www.example.com/api/';
$args=array();
$headers=array(
    'xxxxxx-Username: xxx',
    'xxxxxx-Password: xxx',
    'Content-Type: application/xml'
);

$res=curl( $url, $args, $headers );
if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
    #cool - use $res->response in further processing
    print_r($res->response,true);
}else{
    # useful information will be displayed here...
    printf('<h1>Verbose debug info</h1><pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res->verbose,true));
    printf('<h1>Info</h1><pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res->info,true));
}
```

---

---

**update to indicate how to send POST data**

You use the `$options` parameter to supply different runtime configuration to the curl request, like so:

```
$url='https://www.example.com/api/';
$args=array(
    CURLOPT_POST        =>  true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  $send_body
);
$headers=array(
    'xxxxxx-Username: xxx',
    'xxxxxx-Password: xxx',
    'Content-Type: application/xml'
);
$res=curl( $url, $args, $headers );
```

Comment: Professor, first of all, THANK YOU! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this challenge! <3 I have run the above and bottom line, this is the error I am getting: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version      Is this enough for you to debug? Or would you like to see the whole lot? I would be happy to take this into a chat room if that suits you. Otherwise I will edit out personal url data and send it here, whatever suits you best. Thanks again and I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: There are a whole load of different ciphers available and you might find that you can determine which to use by manually inspecting the SSL certificate ( ie: use the dev tools in browser when you visit the site )

Comment: Professor, following that error, I sort of get the feeling that it might be related to some older version of the cURL/SSL libraries. I am about to start reinstalling a brand new PHP/Curl envirnomnet on a new PC and I will report back my findings! Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Have you tried different curl SSL version constants? Check those available [CURLOPT_SSLVERSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) I no longer have Skype and have never had messenger so apologies for that but if you redact the sensitive data certainly add it to the question - if I don't know how to solve given the full data then there are likely to be hundreds that do!

Comment: Professor, I have added the dubug info in my original question above. I look forward to hear your thoughts. Thank you in advance.